# How to perform this manipulation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**(1)        $ z^2y+xy^2+x^2z-(x^2y+xz^2+y^2z) $**
**(2)        $ (x-y)(y-z)(z-x) $**

How to go from STEP (1) to STEP (2). Nothing I do seems to work. I tried combining terms but that doesn't help.

I do not want to go from step 2 to step 1. I arrived at step 1 in some question and I need to go from 1 to 2 to match my answer given in the textbook.

I see a lot of comments asking me to just expand 2 and arrive at 1. I could see that too but I am really curious to know how it is done the other way around. Added to that, if you get (1) while solving some question, you obviously have to go from 1 to 2 and not from 2 to 1.

Comment: Is it forbidden to just multiply out $(2)$ and the compare it to $(1)$? I don't see the sense of using some "trick".

Comment: Just expanding works fine.

Comment: Note that if $x=y$ the first quantity would be zero ... this means $(x-y)$ is a factor. Similarly $(y-z)$ and $(z-x)$ are factors. So (1) = $k(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ ... just need to find $k$ now !

Comment: @Cotton You can check out my answer. I think that is the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
z^2y+xy^2+x^2z-(x^2y+xz^2+y^2z)
&=z^2y-z^2x+xy^2-x^2y+x^2z-y^2z\\
&=z^2(y-x)+xy(y-x)+z(x^2-y^2)\\
&=z^2(y-x)+xy(y-x)+z(x+y)(x-y)\\
&=(y-x)(z^2+xy-z(x+y))\\
&=(y-x)(z^2-zx+xy-zy)\\
&=(y-x)(z(z-x)+y(x-z))\\
&=(y-x)(z-y)(z-x)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Another method :

Rewrite (1) as

$$-yx^2  + x^2 z + x y^2 - x z^2 - y^2 z + y z^2 + \underline{ xyz - xyz}$$

Group the terms as follows :

$$(\underline{xyz - xz^2 - y^2z + yz^2} ) - ( \underline{ x^2y-x^2z-xy^2+xyz})$$

Factor out $z$ from first underlined expression and $x$ from the second :

$$ = z(xy - xz -y^2 + yz) - x(xy - xz - y^2 + yz)$$

Now it can be easily seen that the two expressions inside the brackets are identical, so factor them out :

$$=(z-x)(xy - xz -y^2 + yz)$$

$$=(z-x)(x(y-z)-y(y-z))$$

$$=(z-x)(y-z)(x-y)$$

As Desired.

**So the "trick" here is to add and subtract $abc$.** It can actually be observed quite easily by multiplying the brackets in $(2)$.

Hope this helps.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pair the positive and negative terms to get one of the factors
\begin{eqnarray*}
z^2y+xy^2+x^2z-(x^2y+xz^2+y^2z) = z^2y -xz^2+xy^2-x^2y +x^2z-y^2z
\end{eqnarray*}
Pull off this factor
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x-y)(-z^2-xy+(x+y)z)   
\end{eqnarray*}
The content of the second bracket is easily shown to be what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the first expression can easily seen to be $0$ for $x=y$ and $x=z$. Considering it as a polynomial in $x\,$ of degree $2$, this means that it factors as $\lambda(x-y)(x-z)$ where the dominant coefficient $\lambda$ must match the coefficient of $x^2$ from the original expression i.e. $\lambda=z-y$.